# Snake bite & setting it on fire

Tags: medical-myths, burns, venom, animal-bites, fire-safety

I heard this from some people in my village that snake venom catches fire like diesel fuel. And they said, one can make a li'l cut around the wound and set it on fire as an immediate action to get more time to reach some medical aid. Now, there are some cases where people have done this and they are still alive(could be their luck as well)

My question is, what could be the health concerns with such a method?
And is it of any worth at all?

Please, keep your answers based on medical theory or some real life cases.
Thank you.

Comment: All 100% false. Making that cut around the wound is useless at best and likely harmful (nerve damage, infection, burns). I'll try to find time to write a proper answer later if someone else doesn't.